# How can I hide the AppBar back button based on the platform?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

I am hoping to hide all `AppBar` back buttons throughout my app for Android users, so that they must use the device's back button instead. But for iOS users, I would like for the `AppBar`'s back button to be present since that is the standard way to navigate.

What is the best way to achieve this and is there a way to do it globally using `AppBarTheme`?

I am aware of `AppBar(automaticallyImplyLeading: false, ...)` but that hides the back button on both iOS and Android devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set that value based on the platform.  You can get the platform with https://pub.dev/packages/platform, like so:

```
AppBar(automaticallyImplyLeading: !Platform.isAndroid, ...)
```

which will make it false on Android, true everywhere else.  You might need to add other platforms if you find it necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply hide it conditionally:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

AppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: !Platform.isAndroid,
  ...,
)
```

This will *only hide the back button **on Android***.

---

[Learn more about `Platform.isAndroid`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform/isAndroid.html).

Comment: You missed a "not".

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Thanks :)